# To count length of each word in sentence by using jQuery ,and send the largest word's length

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var length = 0;
    var j;
    var newStr = str.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0;i<15;i++){
        var lentemp = newStr[i].length();
        if( lentemp >length){
            length === lentemp ;
        }
    }
    return length ;
}; 

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I want to get result as the length of the word which is largest?
I'm new to jQuery.
Can anybody help me to sort this?I'm just learning jQuery and i can't proceed further without finishing this.

Comment: That hardcoded `15` should be `newStr.length`, `length` is a property not a function so remove the parentheses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037076/find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-using-javascript
Ask a question if you cant find the answer online

Comment: You definitely don't need jQuery for this. In fact, your example doesn't use any of the jQuery library. jQuery !== JavaScript; jQuery is a library written in JavaScript.

Comment: @BenilMathew: If that's a duplicate, please vote to close as a duplicate, citing that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `===` this is [**Comparison operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) but you need [**Assignment operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) `=`. Use `=` instead of `===`.

So this line `length === lentemp ;` should be `length = lentemp ;`

---

Also one more thing `length` is not function in javascript so you can't use `length()` remove braces and use `.length`.

This is complete snippet:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var length = 0;
    var j;
    var newStr = str.split(" ");
    console.log(newStr.length);
    for(var i = 0;i<newStr.length;i++){
        var lentemp = newStr[i].length;
        
        if( lentemp >length){
            length = lentemp ;
        }
    }
    return length ;
}; 

alert(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, map the array of strings to their lengths, and then use math.max.apply

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var length = 0;
    var j;
    var newStr = str.split(" ");

    var lengths = newStr.map(function(item) {
        return parseInt(item.length, 10);
    });

    var longest = Math.max.apply(null, lengths);
    return longest;
}; 

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```