# Find longest word in string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently on a task in python and i need help with this and i am to

Write a function called longest which will take a string of space separated words and will return the longest one.

For example:

```
longest("This is Andela") => "Andela"
longest("A") => "A"
```

This is the sample test

```
const assert = require("chai").assert;

describe("Module 10 - Algorithyms", () => {
describe("longest('This Is Andela')", () => {
    let result = longest("This Is Andela");
    it("Should return 'Andela'", () => {
        assert.equal(result, 'Andela');
    });
});

describe("longest('This')", () => {
    let result = longest("This");
    it("Should return 'This'", () => {
        assert.equal(result, 'This');
    });
});

describe("longest(23)", () => {
    let result = longest(23);
    it("Should return ''", () => {
        assert.equal(result, '');
    });
});
});
```

This is what i have tried

```
function longest(str) {
str = "This is Andela";
var words = str.split(' ');
var longest = '';

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (words[i].length > longest.length) {
    longest = words[i];
  }
}
return longest;
}
```

But my code seem to only pass the first test case.Please what do i need to change to pass the other two first case considering i am new to javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31037162/622813

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the longest word in a string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037076/find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: what will be the output if all words inside string is of same length like :- `this code  used`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Is there really a need to spam every answer with the same comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove this line in your function:

```
str = "This is Andela";
```

You function should be (added check if str is string):

```
function longest(str) {
    if(typeof str !== 'string') return '';
    var words = str.split(' ');
    var longest = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i].length > longest.length) {
        longest = words[i];
      }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

Comment: still doesn't pass the test. now the errors are much

Comment: added string check. It's should pass all your tests

Comment: Yes, i added some edits to my answer later. It's checking if `str` is actual string

Comment: what will be the output if all words inside string is of same length like :- `this code used`?

Comment: `might ` because it is longest

Comment: @VictorLeontyev  changed.check now

Comment: in other case, if it is `this code used`, it will return first

Comment: perfect @VictorLeontyev works perfectly Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Simplified code with no arrays and no each statements.

```js
function longer(champ, contender) {
  return (contender.length > champ.length) ? contender: champ;
}

function longestWord(str) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    return words.reduce(longer);
}
console.log(longestWord('This is longest'));
console.log(longestWord('This is longest or may this is more longestest'));
```

Comment: Since when [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) doesn't return an array?

Comment: what will be the output if all words inside string is of same length like :- `this code used`?

Comment: Well the objective is to find the longest word, so if all have same length, you would get the first longest word in the string.

Comment: I like the reduce usage here. Very insightful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
function longest(s){
    return typeof s != 'string' ? '' : s.split(' ').sort( (a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0]
}
```

The input is converted into string through concatenation with an empty string so that it works when a number is passed as well.

Comment: what will be the output if all words inside string is of same length like :- `this code used`?

Comment: Yours passes the first two test but fials the last test `expected '23' to equal ''`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the latest test. I have modified my code! 10x